# How to get JSON content and display it in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I'm making an app using React JS. It's basically supposed to get JSON content and display it in the screen. I know this is supposed to be something really simple, but I am just unable to implement it. Please look into my code and show a way to import and display this JSON in my React. Thanks!!

JSON

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Test",
    "firstName": "Testing",
    "lastName": "Thingy",
    "salary": 5000
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Test",
    "firstName": "Test",
    "lastName": "Thing",
    "salary": 6000
  }
]
```

React JS code in a minimal reproducible example -

```
import thing from "./card.json";

const item = JSON.stringify(thing[0][1]);
const item2 = JSON.stringify(thing[1]);

const ProductCard = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{item}</h1>
      <h1>{item2}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductCard;
```

Comment: please describe the problem in the post - what error do you get? what doesn't work?

Comment: @Janar I don't get the first item on json I get the whole thing can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

If all the objects in JSON is the same you can use the `map` function.
It could look something like.

```
import thing from "./card.json";

const ProductCard = ({ data }) => {
  return (
      <div>
        {data.map(jsonObject => {
            return(
                <div>
                    <h1>{jsonObject.title}</h1>
                    <p>{jsonObject.id}</p>
                    <p>{jsonObject.firstName}</p>
                    <p>{jsonObject.lastName}</p>
                    <p>{jsonObject.salary}</p>
                </div>
                )
            })
        }
      </div>
  );
};

export default ProductCard;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey the above format of JSON is object inside a array so we can access the array elemnet using things[0] but for for object we need to provide the key.
In above you don't need to Stringify the JSON.

```js
import thing from "./card.json";

const item = thing[0].id;
const item2 = thing[1].title;

const ProductCard = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{item}</h1>
      <h1>{item2}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductCard;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wants to get value of one field use this code:

```
const item = data[0].id;
```

but if you wants to read all object as string use this sample:

```
const item2 = JSON.stringify(data[1]);
```